# Reading a complex JSON in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following complex jSON string which gets returned in an Ajax call in jquery 1.8

```
listCountries({"totalResults":3,"countrynames":[
{"countryName":"Afghanistan","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":1,"code":"continent"},
{"countryName":"Albenia","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":2,"code":"continent"},
{"countryName":"Algeria","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":3,"code":"continent"}
]});
```

I want to populate a select box using this JSON data.

I am doing the following

```
 $.getJSON(someurl)
            .success(function (data) {
                var list= "";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.countrynames.length; i++) {
                    list += "<option value='" + data.countrynames[i].lng + "'>" + data.countrynames[i].countryName + "</option>";
                }
$("#names").html(list);
```

However the list does not get populated. Can anyone suggest why. Also is there a better practice to loop through this JSON string and populate select box.

Comment: Your code works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnAph/ Have you checked the response in the console to ensure `data` is coming back as you expect it

Comment: Is the success handler being executed?

Comment: Also works with ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/pnAph/2/. There must be something else happening - can you setup a demo?

Comment: Here's what I did..I went to http://json.parser.online.fr/ and typed the json pasted in my original post..it gives an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token l. Can anyone explain what's wrong and how to handle this error in my code

Comment: I also observe that in both the demos, you haven't considered that the json string begins with listCountries. Is that the reason your demo works and mine doesn't

Comment: @user1089173 what is the contents of `listCountries`?

Comment: it comes with the JSON string at the beginning..check my post for the entire json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is not returning JSON.  It is returning [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  JSONP is an extra step you must take when you request data from a different domain.

This is JSON:

```
{"totalResults":3,"countrynames":[
{"countryName":"Afghanistan","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":1,"code":"continent"},
{"countryName":"Albenia","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":2,"code":"continent"},
{"countryName":"Algeria","fName":"parks,area, ...","lng":3,"code":"continent"}
]}
```

Your AJAX call doesn't seem to be requesting JSONP, so it seems as though your server code is incorrect.  One option would be to fix your server code to return JSON.

Or if you cannot, then this code will work.

```
$.getJSON(someurl)
    .success(function (data) {
        // remove the listCountries function name, and the two parentheses.  
        // Then convert the string into an object
        data = JSON.parse(data.substr(14, data.length - 16))

        // you forgot the select opening & closing tags
        var list= "<select>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.countrynames.length; i++) {
            list += "<option value='" + data.countrynames[i].lng + "'>" + data.countrynames[i].countryName + "</option>";
        // you forgot the closing bracket
        }
        list += '</select>';
        $("#names").html(list);
    }
```